# Does the Parseval identity imply the completeness of an orthonormal system?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, orthogonality, complete-spaces

Let $V$ be an inner product space which is not complete. Can there by an orthonormal system satisfying the Parseval identity for each vector but which is not complete i.e the only vector orthogonal to each of its elements is zero?

Comment: Is this a different way to rephrase your question: if I have an orthonormal system in a Hilbert space satisfying the Parseval identity, then any vector orthogonal to the entire orthonormal system is the zero vector. Is the same true if I replace the Hilbert space by any inner product space? To answer that, I would just think about the completion: there you still have an orthonormal system, and you should think about whether you also have the Parseval identity. If you do then by the previous statement you have completeness.

Comment: @Ian I think the Parseval identity carries to the completion by continuity of the inner product. So I think the conclusion is there can *not* be such an imcomplete orthonormal system.

Comment: I agree (though I didn't write out the details yet).

Comment: Suppose $\|x\|^2=\sum_{\alpha}|(x,e_\alpha)|^2$ for all $x$. If $y\perp e_{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha$, it follows that $\|y\|^2=0$.